# grep and grep -f differences

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file with the following 3 lines:

file.txt

```
aaa|
bbb|
ccc|
```

and another file with one line:

regex.txt

```
^aaa\|
```

`$grep ^aaa\| file.txt` yields:

```
aaa|
```

`$grep -f regex.txt file.txt` yields:

```
aaa|
bbb|
ccc|
```

Why are the results different for `grep -f` and `grep`?

```
$grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 3.1

$lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using grep with [basic regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html#Basic-vs-Extended). `grep ^aaa\| file.txt` is the same as typing `grep "^aaa|" file.txt`. While reading the file `grep -f regex.txt file.txt` is the same as `grep "^aaa\|" file.txt`., the escaped `|` means match `^aaa` or `""` which matches anything.

Comment: In particular, on the command line the _shell_ processes and removes the backslash (or the double-quotes you propose). While if the pattern is in a file, there is no shell involved, so `grep`s regex engine sees the backslash. It's probably easiest to single-quote any such patterns on the shell command line, to ensure minimal processing by the shell. Also, it should be noted that `\|` for alternation in BRE is a GNU thing, and not standard.

Answer (score 0):

When using regexp in file, you do not need the `\` (escape). When in file it is treated as the `\` char. In command it is treated as escape and ignored (due to the lack of quoting of the expression).